# how do I select an element with multiple class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've found a similar question but mine is different. Thanks:)

here's the html

```
<div class="a c h">I'm here1</div>
<div class="a h">I'm here2</div>
```

I only want to get all elements where class is **exactly** "a h". I've tried these selector:

```
$(".a.h")
$(".a.h").not("[class='c']")
```

but it picks up "a c h" as well.

Any ideas how it can be done? Thanks very much.

Ps. I did search the net but found nothing there.

Comment: You want to be '**exactly** "a h"'? So, *not* 'h a'? Or do you mean only elements with those two classes (and no other classes)?

Comment: Don't use the attribute selector in not. `.not("[class='c']")` only excludes elements that have only class=c, which of course is none of them. Use `.not(".c")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select the exact value: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/h34b5fgc/)

```
$('[class="a h"]')
```

If the order varies, I guess you could select both variations: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/rn153mrn/)

```
$('[class="a h"], [class="h a"]')
```

---

..or just negate elements with a class of `.c`: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/vh2j13qs/)

```
$(".a.h:not(.c)")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".a.h").not('.c');
```

here is the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/yrb2m5r1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want only elements with those specific classes (regardless of the order of those classes):

```
// selects all elements with a class of 'a' and 'h':
$('.a.h').filter(function(){
    // keeps only those elements with only two classes
    // (to avoid having to hard-code the classes that you
    // don't want to 'accidentally' select):
    return this.classList.length === 2;
});
```

```js
$('.a.h').filter(function() {
  return this.classList.length === 2;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

```css
div::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a c h"></div>
<div class="a h"></div>
<div class="h a"></div>
<div class="a m h"></div>
```

If, instead, you want to select only those elements with class `a` and class `h`, in that specific order:

```
$('.a.h').filter(function () {
    return this.className === 'a h';
});
```

```js
$('.a.h').filter(function() {
  return this.className === 'a h';
}).css('color', 'red');
```

```css
div::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a c h"></div>
<div class="a h"></div>
<div class="h a"></div>
<div class="a m h"></div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).